# Why does Flutter GridView display the wrong images after correctly removing an item?

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I have a GridView.builder that displays images from an array called _storyAssets. If I remove one of the images, the array is updated correctly, BUT the view is NOT. Even though the array that is passed to the GridView.builder is correct, the image that I removed remains on the screen and ONLY the last image in the view is removed. When I inspect the individual items being sent to the GridView, they are correct. The removed item is NOT in the data, but it is still visible on screen, while the last item that GridView builds that should still be visible is not.

Here is my remove function:

```
  void removeAsset(tourAsset) {
final List<TourAsset> tempArray = [];
_storyAssets.forEach((item) {
  if (item.ref != tourAsset.ref) {
    tempArray.add(item);
  }
});
setState(() {
  _storyAssets = tempArray;
});
```

}

Here's the GridView.builder:

```
GridView.builder(
                    itemCount: _storyAssets.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      // crossAxisCount: 1
                      crossAxisCount: _storyAssets.length <= 1 ? 1 : 2,
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      print(
                          'GridView Story Asset: ${_storyAssets[index].ref} ');
                      return Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: Container(
                          width: 200,
                          height: 200,
                          child: AssetThumbnail(
                            onTap: removeAsset,
                            asset: _storyAssets[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    })
```

Here are my print statements that show the correct item was removed. NOTE that the bike image is still showing in the print statements when the GridView builds, but is not visible on screen:

I/flutter ( 5800): 1. asset being removed: media/RvoGlxBvpUY1sg6vi5KA5guDzVn1/5c8513a2-e89b-4a3e-ad53-746282d79f08
I/flutter ( 5800): 2.forEach item: media/RvoGlxBvpUY1sg6vi5KA5guDzVn1/77300f96-b551-4dc7-b73a-769fdfd6485e removing: media/RvoGlxBvpUY1sg6vi5KA5guDzVn1/5c8513a2-e89b-4a3e-ad53-746282d79f08
I/flutter ( 5800): 2.forEach item: media/RvoGlxBvpUY1sg6vi5KA5guDzVn1/5c8513a2-e89b-4a3e-ad53-746282d79f08 removing: media/RvoGlxBvpUY1sg6vi5KA5guDzVn1/5c8513a2-e89b-4a3e-ad53-746282d79f08
I/flutter ( 5800): 2.forEach item: tours/1QRxJQKKXJhaHqkyh5vK/hue_cyclo_tour.jpg removing: media/RvoGlxBvpUY1sg6vi5KA5guDzVn1/5c8513a2-e89b-4a3e-ad53-746282d79f08
I/flutter ( 5800): 3. storyAssets array before removal:
I/flutter ( 5800): media/RvoGlxBvpUY1sg6vi5KA5guDzVn1/77300f96-b551-4dc7-b73a-769fdfd6485e
I/flutter ( 5800): media/RvoGlxBvpUY1sg6vi5KA5guDzVn1/5c8513a2-e89b-4a3e-ad53-746282d79f08
I/flutter ( 5800): tours/1QRxJQKKXJhaHqkyh5vK/hue_cyclo_tour.jpg
I/flutter ( 5800): 4. temp array:
I/flutter ( 5800): media/RvoGlxBvpUY1sg6vi5KA5guDzVn1/77300f96-b551-4dc7-b73a-769fdfd6485e
I/flutter ( 5800): tours/1QRxJQKKXJhaHqkyh5vK/hue_cyclo_tour.jpg
I/flutter ( 5800): ^^^^^^^STORY EDITOR^^^^^^^^
I/flutter ( 5800): 5. storyAssets in the build:
I/flutter ( 5800): media/RvoGlxBvpUY1sg6vi5KA5guDzVn1/77300f96-b551-4dc7-b73a-769fdfd6485e
I/flutter ( 5800): tours/1QRxJQKKXJhaHqkyh5vK/**hue_cyclo_tour.jpg**
I/flutter ( 5800): GridView Story Asset: media/RvoGlxBvpUY1sg6vi5KA5guDzVn1/77300f96-b551-4dc7-b73a-769fdfd6485e
I/flutter ( 5800): GridView Story Asset: tours/1QRxJQKKXJhaHqkyh5vK/hue_cyclo_tour.jpg

Here are screen shots. The item that I removed ends in 08. The bicycle image should still be visible, but is not:
[image]

[image]

Comment: share some more code. your widget class

Comment: I think there might be an indexing problem with your code. Are you fetching images directly from firestore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you don't provide the code for the `AssetThumbnail` the problem you describe sounds like a `Widget Key` problem, which is common if you use Stateful widgets in a collection.

Instead of calling
`AssetThumbnail(onTap: removeAsset, asset: _storyAssets[index])` try
`AssetThumbnail(key: ObjectKey(_storyAssets[index]), onTap: removeAsset, asset: _storyAssets[index])`

The key associates the thumbnail widget with the actual contents. This [article](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d) explains it well.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!  That was the issue. Much appreciated.